# Word to describe factor of x or 1/x

Tags: prime-factorization, multiplicative-function

There is a well known video of a helicopter with 5 evenly spaced rotor blades where the rotor is synced with a digital camera's frame rate.

Assuming the camera is at 60 hertz (60 frames per second), the rotor must be spinning at x/5 * 60. Where it seems like x could be any integer. However, let's say x is 1. So the rotor is spinning at 12 hertz. It's quite possible that in actuality, it's spinning slower than that, so my equation of `rotor rate = x/5*60` seems to be incorrect.

The reason is that given the footage, it's impossible to say if a single rotor is spinning all the way around, or just 1/5, or 3/5 around, etc. Or 8/5 around.

What is the description/name of the relationship between x and 60? It's not a factor is it?

Here's the original vid:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yr3ngmRuGUc

Comment: why not describe x as a multiple of 12?

Comment: "*The rotor must be spinning at either 60 hertz or $\frac{x}{5}\cdot 60$ hertz where $x$ is an integer*"... the first case is covered by the second case by letting $x=5$, so there is no reason to mention it.  Further, the second case can be simplified to say "*the rotor must be spinning at $x\cdot 12$ hertz where $x$ is an integer.*"  Here, I would call $x$ a factor of the total hertz, but certainly not necessarily one of $60$.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but I suppose $x$ needs to be, more specifically, a nonnegative integer. If $x$ were allowed to be $0$ then it would no longer be an illusion but it would actually be hovering.

Comment: @DavidDiaz here is where it gets confusing. The rotor can obviously be spinning slower than 12 hertz, so I guess x does not need to be an integer. I am not sure how to explain it that's why I brought forth the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be describing here is *aliasing* or [*folding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Folding) where your system's frequency cannot be distinguished from another frequency that's reflected across the [Nyquist Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency).

But that's not $1/x$: if your sampling rate is, say, $60\text{Hz}$, your Nyquist frequency is $30 \text{Hz}$, and phenomena running at $25 \text{Hz}$ will have aliases at $60k - 25 = (35 + 60k)\text{Hz}$ and $(25 + 60k)\text{Hz}$.

Comment: Honestly this doesn't make that much sense to me, where the heck did you get 30hz from, 60hz/2?